# Delphi IDE - How to stop snap to edge of screen?

Tags: delphi, ide

Windows (10) has an option to disable snap to sides or corners of screen. (Settings > System > Multitasking > Work with multiple windows > Snap windows.)  I have that disabled, and that stops all application windows from snapping to screen edges.

Except Delphi IDE -- it continues to snap to screen edges.  So I'm assuming there's a setting somewhere in Delphi that has to be set specially to stop it from doing this snapping behavior. Anyone know where it is?  For what it's worth, it's not affected by Tools > Options > User Interface > Docking > "Auto drag docking".  That appears to be to do with docking tool panel windows into other windows.

Edit 2023-12-30
This issue was present in RAD Studio 10, and got worse in 11.
This issue is fixed in RAD Studio 12.
See issue RSP-40327

Comment: I'm not aware such an option exists.

Comment: It used to be the case (I don't know if it still is) that Delphi (VCL) applications have a hidden application window, so the main form was not the real main form from Window's perspective.  (If that's no longer the case, I'm sure someone will let us know!) 
 So I'm speculating that this might have something to do with your issue.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with Windows 11 22H2 and Delphi 11.3.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment I appreciate your commenting, but why would the presence of a hidden application window somehow cause Windows to decide to snap Delphi's windows to the screen edges when that Windows option was turned off?  I am fairly sure it's Delphi that is treating itself specially, not Windows.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment: The question is about the Delphi IDE's behavior, not general Delphi applications.

Comment: As @KenWhite said, my post is about behavior of the IDE windows. Windows of VCL applications do not exhibit the snapping behavior.  I also would appreciate comments about what happens in Windows 11, specifically stating that it's IDE windows that do or don't snap.  I'm filing a bug report and could add that detail.

Comment: Bug report RSP-42332

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed that it was about the IDE.